# What I have learned so far in my journey of life

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context

The point is, I want to write a book about my life. Which one of this sentences that good in grammar and fit for my book?

> What I have learned so far in *my journey of life*
>
> What I have learned so far in *journey of my life*

And based on this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/186331/in-my-journey-vs-on-my-journey), should I use "**in**" or "**on**" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you hire someone to help you with your English as your question has a number of mistakes....

Answer (score 1):

The second example is incorrect; you would need "the" before "journey."

Your question about "in" versus "on" is a stylistic one. I would suggest "on," because typically you go *on* a journey.

Comment: So you prefer "What I have learned so far on the journey of my life" ?